# File Permission issues while launching App

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-external-storage, file-access, android-developer-api

We plan to launch an app which needs access to user's folder permission to upload/save documents. However, play console is rejecting the app as it does not believe it is a core functionality. We have added the function "Manage_External_Storage" in our build but it is still rejecting as a core functionality error. We have also uploaded a video depicting the use case as well.
The error is :
**Not a core feature. The app feature that you declared as dependent on the All files access permission didn’t meet the policy review requirements for critical core functionality.
**

We want to ensure we can access user's storage access to retrieve documents for our verification process. We have uploaded a use case video but still got rejected.

Comment: Unclear what you consider to be 'user storage' or 'user folder'. Further you can get all documents from device with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE without needing any permission.

Comment: check out [THIS](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955?hl=en) doc and remove `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` perm. further find (another) way for your files access (e.g. using `Intent`s suggested above)